# Retrieve access token by achieving SSO requirements for Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: single-sign-on, google-apps-marketplace

I have configured my app in google apps marketplace SDK. The scopes mentioned in it will be added to the admin console once the app is installed. In order to access the google apps data, my app needs access token. In order to achieve this I used [google sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow#implementing_the_one-time-code_flow). But however this again shows me the user consent page which should not appear according to the [SSO requirements](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/practices#4_use_one-click_single_sign-on). So how am I supposed to get the access token for my app by satisfying all the SSO requirents.